# The proper Solr Tokenizer to tokenize text while preserving special characters

Tags: solr, token, tokenize

Which tokenizer is appropriate to do this:

```
input: "This-something is something."
output: ["] [This] [-] [something] [is] [something] [.] ["]
```

I tried with `solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory`, but this removes all the special characters. Also tried `solr.KeepWordFilterFactory`, with all the special characters in `keepwords.txt`. But this doesn't work either.

Any suggestions? I am on Solr 3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think there is an out of the box Tokenizer for your specific requirement.
You can create a new one specific to the requirements and easily have Solr use it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up writing a customized filter and import as a plugin to Solr. Works out well. Thanks! In case anyone having the same issue: http://e-mats.org/2008/06/writing-a-solr-analysis-filter-plugin/